# Adding primary key for partition table in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

```
CREATE TABLE list_parted (a int, b int) PARTITION BY LIST(a);

CREATE TABLE list_part_1 PARTITION OF list_parted FOR VALUES IN (1, 2, 3);
CREATE TABLE list_part_2 PARTITION OF list_parted FOR VALUES IN (6, 7, 8);

INSERT INTO list_parted VALUES (7, 77);

ALTER TABLE list_parted ADD PRIMARY KEY (b);
```

When am trying to add the primary key for the above table, I get this error:

> ERROR: insufficient columns in PRIMARY KEY constraint definition
>   SQL state 0A000
>   Detail: PRIMARY KEY constraint on table "list_parted" lacks column "a" which is part of the partition key.

Answer (score 21):

You need to include the partitioning column in the declaration of the PK or create a UNIQUE idx with both columns, is the same result.

```
CREATE TABLE customer(
  id int,
  country_code character varying(5),
  name character varying(100),
  PRIMARY KEY (id, country_code)
)
PARTITION BY LIST (country_code);
```

Comment: Doing so worked for me like a charm and thank you. However, filling up the table with the data failed (using the GUI option Import/Export). Any ideas why would it fail ? Without the partitions I created I can import the CSV data to the table normally.